# printf skipped after scanf statement [C]

Tags: c, printf, scanf, buffer, stdout

I'm struggling to understand how buffers work in c. I'm trying to create a terminal program that involves the following `do-while` loop

```
do {
        
        system("clear");
        
        // printing the updated canvas (the following double loop fill the terminal with the box character except for the last two rows: rows is declared as the number of rows of the terminal - 2)
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                if (canvas[i][j] == 0) printf("%s", dark_box);
                else if (canvas[i][j] == 1) printf("%s", light_box);
            }
        }       
        
        // reading a new command
        printf("Insert a command: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", command);
        printf("TRY");
        sleep(5);
        
    } while (strcmp(command, "exit") != 0);
```

Now the problem is that when I run this code the program seems to work just fine until the `scanf` function, but then, it seems to skip the `printf("TRY")` statement, executing the `sleep(5)` directly. `TRY` is printed just after the `system(clear)` call appearing at the upper left corner of the terminal. This makes the rest of the character shift to the right, therefore the terminal is filled with `TRY` and a number of characters such that ends up filling with 3 boxes the penultimate line.

How could this issue be solved?

Comment: Please don't use the `%[]` format to read lines, it seldom does what you expect. Instead use `fgets`.

Comment: As for the problem with your current code, there could be many different problems. One problem is that you don't print a trailing newline in your `printf` calls. The `printf` function writes to the `stdout` stream. When `stdout` is connected to a terminal or console, it's *line buffered*, which means that output is written to the terminal or console itself when you print a newline `'\n'`. Since you don't do that, all your printing will be buffered up, and not actually written, until the buffer becomes full or is flushed some other way.

Comment: If you must use `scanf` then rearrange it as `scanf(" %[^\n]", command);`. Don't kludge trailing whitespace - filter (any amount of) leading whitespace.

Comment: To ensure a line without CR is effectively transmitted to the console, you can add `flush(stdout);` after the `printf("...");`.

Comment: I've tried using scanf(" %[^\n]", command), but the problems still remains, it seems that the following printf is being skipped. I've tried printf("TRY\n"), this time the code seems to work. @dalfaB the fflush has to be included after the first or the second printf call?

Comment: It must be included after every `printf` call that does not end with an `\n`  and that you want to be printed without delay.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably not use `scanf()` here. Use `fgets()` as follows:

```
do {
    
    system("clear");
    
    // printing the updated canvas (the following double loop fill the terminal with the box character except for the last two rows: rows is declared as the number of rows of the terminal - 2)
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (canvas[i][j] == 0) printf("%s", dark_box);
            else if (canvas[i][j] == 1) printf("%s", light_box);
        }
    }       
    
    // reading a new command
    printf("Insert a command: ");
    fgets(command, strlen(command), stdio);
    printf("TRY");
    sleep(5);
    
} while (strcmp(command, "exit") != 0);
```

Make sure to include strings.h!

Comment: "Use gets() as follows:" **NO!** Never ever use `gets`. It was removed from the standard decades ago for good reason. Instead use `fgets`.

Comment: Also, this answer does not address the issue of buffering `TRY` until `sleep(5)` was executed which is the main topic of the question.

Comment: `fgets(command, strlen(command), stdio);` --> `fgets(command, sizeof command, stdin);`. Don't use `strlen` here for at least three reasons: if `command` hasn't been initialized then calling `strlen` on it has undefined behavior; if `command` holds a string it may be shorter than user input causing `fgets` to truncate user input; in the best case the length of the string `command` is one-less than the array capacity (which is what `fgets` wants). `stdio` is not an IO stream in C; this should be `stdin`. `fgets` reads `\n` into the string when possible; this should be removed as in OP code.

Comment: WIth the update, some new issues were added (besides wrong size for `fgets` as mentioned above): There is no `strings.h` header but `string,h`. The buffer filled by `fgets` will contain the newline character that either needs to be removed from the buffer or the string for comparison needs to contain it as well: `"exit\n"` Otherwise `strcmp` will never return 0.